Refine Dev, how can i implement RTL in version 4?
So, I'm currently working on a project that is Arabic only, and it is my first time using Refine DEV.
On the websites documentation, I didn't find anything related to RTL in version 4.
So I wanted to check what the proper way is to implement the Arabic language + RTL.
I tried switching the lang to ar.
And adding dir=ar as a prop for the whole body, do you think that the correct way?

you should add dir="rtl" , and for the CSS, you can add direction: "rtl"

There is a known issue, we are fixing it. You can check issues/PR on GitHub repo
